# Best approach to download files from Azure Blob Storage using file urls

Tags: download, powerbi, azure-blob-storage, powerapps

What is the best approach for the following requirement: I have files stored in Azure Blob Storage with a Private endpoint. I need to show to the user,  a table with a column containing these file URLs in the browser. When a user clicks on the link, it should either open the file in a new tab or download the file.

I could show the URLs and download files using the Power BI report when the Blob Storage has public access. But in my scenario, it's a Private endpoint. I tried appending the SAS token to the URL, and that also worked, but in this case, SAS token is visible in the browser which is not allowed in my case. So this also does not work for my scenario.

Can we achieve this using Power BI or Power Apps or any other tools/api?
Could you please suggest the steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

- If you need download blob through browser with private container, you need `Blob URL + SAS` token because it provides read and writes to access blobs.
- If you are using public container, you can download with `Blob URL` through browser.

There is no option to call your Blob URL by hiding SAS token.
As workaround, if you need to hide the SAS token from the user and try to access the blob, you can make use of Power Automate connector here:

[image]

I have connected to my Azure blob storage with these Power Automate connectors. 1) I have first connected to my Blob URL endpoint> And created a SAS URI with this connector.
[image]

2. The SAS URI is created successfully by the connector, and I have saved the SAS token inside the compose variable for it to be hidden.

[image]

Later I call an HTTP trigger to trigger the SAS token and get the Image content as HTTP body in the output.

[image]

[image]
When I decode the HTTP body content> I get my Blob Image successfully.

You can convert base64 to image you can use this [link](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image#:%7E:text=How%20to%20convert%20Base64%20to%20image%20online%201,on%20the%20filename%20link%20to%20download%20the%20image.):

[image]

If you want your users to access this Blob, you can further convert this b64 encoded string into Image and save the file in OneDrive, SharePoint for your users to access you can refer this [link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-blob-Content-isn-t-giving-any-output-as-my-file-size-is/td-p/1191783) by eric-cheng.

If you want to Email your users the Blob file, that can also be done by using Outlook, Gmail, etc connectors later.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try this approach. In my case files are different, it may be an image, pdf file, or zip file like that. This Base64 conversion works for all these ? or do we need to handle separately for each file type?

Comment: Yeah, here its converts image type if you need to try different files you can use SharePoint.

Comment: Hi, I was trying the above approach using Power Automate. But I got stuck and came to know that Power Automate and Power Apps does not support connection with Azure Blob storage if the Blob storage is behind the firewall. I count not connect to Blob storage and getting firewall issues. Is there any other way to proceed in this case? Thanks.